# eMMC Backward Compatability

Tags: flash

I would like to use eMMC as boot device in my design. I am planning to use a 8GB, version 5.1 eMMC(THGBMHG6C1LBAIL). But the processor,to which the eMMC is to be connected,supports only eMMC 4.4 version, with 4-bit IO mode.

Can you please clarify me the following.

1.Can the latest version of eMMC still be able to work with the processor version.

2. Generally,can we connect any latest version of eMMC to processor that supports older versions and still get that working.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing what the processor is, you've already answered your first question - "supports only eMMC 4.4 version"

Comment: This might be relevant reading: https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-332187

Comment: In the [datasheet](http://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/791/THGBMHG6C1LBAIL_5F00_THGBMDG5D1LBAIL.pdf) for that part there is a note under one of the tables - "For compatibility with e-MMCs that support the v4.2 standard or earlier, host should not use >26MHz before switching to high-speed interface timing." which seems to imply it is possible.